# Knockout validation valueUpdate depending on attribute error

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

Is is possible to change the attribute valueUpdate from "onblur" to "keyup" depending on if the attribute has an error attached?

I want to mimick the way validation is done in jQuery Validation, and first do validation on blur, and afterwards do validation on keyup.

Is this possible?

EDIT: 
Let me just clarify and give an example. I do not mind that binding to the model occurs on "keyup", what I do mind is that the user is shown an error message, before even given the chance to finish typing. Instead, if I take example in validating an email address. If the user types in an invalid email I would like the error to show on blur, and if the user puts focus on the field again to correct the error I would like the error to disappear once the error is corrected. On the other hand, if the user types in a valid email to begin with, and later introduces an error, the error should show immediately.

SECOND EDIT:
So I've given it some thought, and I believe that the validation shouldn't interfere with model binding, instead the changes should be made to the displaying of error messages. As stated, I would like the error to appear immediately after the error occurs, but only after a change event happened on the relevant field.

I made this fiddle that *almost* works, but it should show exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

http://jsfiddle.net/mntm1bne/3/

```
<div data-bind="validationOptions: {messageTemplate: 'myCustomTemplate'}">    
    <input data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate: 'keyup', event: {change: firstName.enableD}" />
    <br />
    <input data-bind="value: lastName" />

    <div data-bind="if: firstName.isD">
        Firstname is dirty!
    </div>

    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
    <div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/html" id="myCustomTemplate">
    <span data-bind="visible: field.isD && !field.isValid(), attr: { title: field.error }">X</span>
</script>

ko.extenders.trackChange = function(target, track) {
  if (track) {
    target.isD = ko.observable(false);
    target.enableD = function() {
        console.log("enable!");
      target.isD(true);
    }
  }
  return target;
};

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable().extend({ trackChange: true, required: { message: "firstName" }, number: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 100
    });
    self.lastName = ko.observable().extend({ required: { message: "lastName" }});  
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Specifically, the error lies in the first validation message, that is shown on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it properly, you'd rewrite the `valueUpdate` binding so that it takes an observable, and your observable would be based on whether the value has an error.

That sounds hard, so I went with something a little hackier. I substituted an `event` binding for `valueUpdate`. It fires on keydown and if the validated variable is not valid, updates its value from the input (using `event.target`). The value will always be updated on blur, so I didn't have to handle that.

```js
var viewModel = {
  num1: ko.observable(50).extend({
    number: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  }),
  maybeEvaluate: function(data, event) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!viewModel.num1.isValid()) {
        viewModel.num1(event.target.value);
      }
    }, 0);
    return true;
  }

};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
.validationMessage {
  color: Red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.min.js"></script>
0-100:
<input data-bind="value: num1, event: {keydown: maybeEvaluate}" />
<span class="validationMessage" data-bind="validationMessage: num1"></span>
<br />
<input />
```

Here's another approach, based on [protected observables](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html). The original design of protected observables was to give you the option to commit or reset changes. I have an event force a commit on blur, and the protected is modified to auto-commit on receiving a new value if the current value is invalid. (I didn't need the reset routine, so I took that out, so be aware the `protectedObservable` definition is customized.)

**Update** Based on your comment (and also on the fact that I hadn't included the required libs), I've updated the second example so that if the field has ever had an error, it becomes continuously-validating.

```js
ko.protectedObservable = function(initialValue) {
  //private variables
  var _actualValue = ko.observable(initialValue),
    _tempValue = initialValue,
    hasHadError = false;

  //computed observable that we will return
  var result = ko.computed({
    //always return the actual value
    read: function() {
      return _actualValue();
    },
    //stored in a temporary spot until commit
    write: function(newValue) {
      _tempValue = newValue;
      if (!result.isValid()) {
        hasHadError = true;
      }
      if (hasHadError) {
        result.commit();
      }
    }
  }).extend({
    notify: "always"
  });

  //if different, commit temp value
  result.commit = function() {
    if (_tempValue !== _actualValue()) {
      _actualValue(_tempValue);
    }
  };

  return result;
};

var viewModel = {
  num1: ko.protectedObservable(50).extend({
    number: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  })
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
.validationMessage {
  color: Red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.min.js"></script>
0-100:
<input data-bind="value: num1, valueUpdate: 'input', event: {blur: num1.commit}" />
<span class="validationMessage" data-bind="validationMessage: num1"></span>
<br />
<input />
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer, The first answer doesn't entirely mimick jQuery Validation though, and I fear that my explanation of the wanted behavior wasn't precise. What I am trying to achieve is "If the user types in an invalid email I would like the error to show on blur, and if the user puts focus on the field again to correct the error I would like the error to disappear once the error is corrected. AND, if the user introduces an error once more, it will show immediately".

Comment: I tried playing around (https://jsfiddle.net/1Lxxpqcf/1/) with inspiration from https://roysvork.wordpress.com/2014/01/12/tracking-changes-to-complex-viewmodels-with-knockout-js/, but I believe my desired behavior isn't really supported by knockout-validation, at least not to my knowledge. Perhaps I will have to patch the validation plugin, so I am able to supply a function that will determine if an error message should be shown.
Your ideas are very welcome - it seems you are experienced with Knockout.

Comment: @darkdark I also updated your fiddle. You can see that I now track and test whether the item has had an error. https://jsfiddle.net/1Lxxpqcf/2/

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've been trying different things out for a while. I'm accepting this answer because your second solution fits my description exactly - thanks!